# No effect on my detailview when performing an action in a popover

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, popover

I've got a popover with a tableview, when I select a cell I would like to load text in a textview on my DetailViewController. Here is the code :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
//  object creation
Pebkac *pebkac = pebkacsFavArray[indexPath.row];

// Set the pebkac text
NSLog(@"Fav Pebkac title : %@",pebkac.title);
NSLog(@"Fav desc : %@", pebkac.description);
self.detailViewController.textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", pebkac.description];

// Set the font size
self.detailViewController.textView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[Preferences startupSize]];

// Set Detail title
self.detailViewController.title = pebkac.title;
}
```

The result of NSLog is correct but the textView.text doesn't change, same for the detailViewController.title

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a number of things but the question is a little light on details. Have you confirmed that `detailViewController` is a valid object (!= nil)? Are you using nibs? If so, have you double checked that your outlets are linked properly? I'd include more details if you've still got issues.

Comment: I use storyboards but my popover is in a xib file, outlets seem correctly linked

Comment: While debugging did you ensure that you are assigning the text / title to a valid object? If neither works then it's possible that the `detailViewController` doesn't actually exist. Just before assigning your text / title try printing the value of `detailViewController` by typing `po [self detailViewController]` in the debug console.

Answer (score 0):

In This code it is not clear that what are u doing with `self.detailViewController`. It should be refresh to show title and `UITextView`'text. The way to do this is to call its `viewWillAppear` Method or make a `refresh` Method in `detailViewController`, and call it in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: How I do a refresh method in my detailViewController ?

Comment: use [self.detailViewController viewWillAppear:YES]; at last in didSelectRowAtIndexPath. Hope it will work

Comment: Same result, nothing change :(